# What is the full list of extras for Intent.ACTION_PICK?

Tags: android, android-intent

I recently started to use intent to pick and crop images. I found out that in addition of using libraries, it can be done with `Intent`s.
So here is my code to pick one:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_SELECT_IMG);
```

I founded this [ACTION_PICK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK), but there is no documents for `extra`s that can be sent to OS. Does any body knows the full list of these extras?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow this link : https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/f06e70ebe8ca52fbbbe2

May be you can get something as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it can be done with Intents.

Not reliably.

> So here is my code to pick one

That will not perform a cropping operation on millions of Android devices, as there is no requirement for any Android device to have an `ACTION_PICK` activity for `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` that supports those undocumented, unsupported extras.

Even for the subset of devices that happen to pay attention to some of those extras:

- You do not know what will be done with those extras
- You do not know what the resulting UI will be like for the user
- You do not know how the results will be delivered, what format they will be in, etc.

> I founded this ACTION_PICK, but there is no documents for extras that can be sent to OS

That is because there are none that are part of the Android SDK.

> Does any body knows the full list of these extras?

There would need to be a list per device model, for over 20,000 device models. We have a difficult enough time getting manufacturers to support the *documented* `Intent` extras, let alone undocumented ones.

Please use a [cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45), rather than rely upon undocumented, unsupported `Intent` extras that will deliver unpredictable results.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do I must use both `image-picker` and `image-cropper`lib? or there is one lib for both?

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi: Using `ACTION_PICK` to pick an image may be fine, just without all those extras and without any assumptions that the images will be cropped. The image cropper libraries should support a `Uri` that you get back from `ACTION_PICK` (if the one you try does not, try another library). There are [image picker libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157?sort=created), and it is possible that there is an image-picker library that has a built-in cropping feature. I have not used image picker libraries and so cannot comment on their features.